# This simple mergeSort code is giving an incorrect answer. Can someone find the bug?

Tags: javascript, mergesort, lexical

The problem seems to be that the mergeSort partitions [300,200, 100] into [300,200] and [100]. Then it successfully merges and sorts [300,200] into [200,300]. The problem occurs now: instead of merging [200,300] with [100], the algorithm runs a sort procedure between [300] with [100]. I have a suspicion that the problem is because of Javascript's closure, because of which the value of j gets interpreted differently at some point. Can someone help me?

```
function mergeSort(A,start,end){
    console.log("Sorting " + A + " between " + start + " and " + end)
    if (start==end){
        console.log("Reached singleton element: " + A[start])
        return;
    } 

    j = Math.floor((end+start)/2);

    mergeSort(A,start,j);
    console.log("Sorted " + A + " between " + start + " and " + j + ". Now sorting between " + (j+1) + " and " + end)
    mergeSort(A,(j+1),end);
    merge(A,start,(j+1),end);
    return A
}  

function merge(A,s,p,e){ 
    var i = s;
    var j = p;
    var finalArray = [];
    while(i < p && j < e+1){
        if (A[i] <= A[j]){
            finalArray[i+j-s-p] = A[i];
            i++
        } 
        else if (A[j] < A[i]){
               finalArray[i+j-s-p] = A[j];
               j++
        }  
    }

    if (i == p){
        while (j < e+1 ){
            finalArray[i-s+j-p] = A[j];
            j++
        }
    }

    if (j == e+1){
        while (i < p ){
            finalArray[i-s +j-p] = A[i];
            i++ 
       }    
    }

    for(var q = s; q <e+1;q++){
        A[q] = finalArray[q-s]
    }
}



A = [300,200, 100] // Gives [ 200, 100, 300 ]
mergeSort(A, 0, (A.length-1));
```

Comment: Single-letter variable names make it quite difficult to figure out what your code is doing or is intending to do (which is an issue both for other readers of your code, and for you yourself later).

Comment: Why don't you use `let` instead of `var` everywhere and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I'm not very versed in javascript, but are you sure you can just assign to random indices in the array without the array already being that size? Just use push.

Comment: Your last two if statements are unnecessary (just use the while loops), and the else if statement can just be an else.

Answer (score 1):

It is a scoping issue. Changing the declaration of j fixes it:

```
let j = Math.floor((end+start)/2);
```

I refactored the merge function. Only reason I didn't rename the variables is that I'm on mobile. Someone with more js knowledge probably has more improvements:

```
function merge(A,s,p,e) { 
    let i = s;
    let j = p;
    let finalArray = [];
    while(i < p && j <= e) {
        if (A[i] <= A[j]) {
            finalArray.push(A[i])
            i++
        } 
        else {
            finalArray.push(A[j])
            j++
        }  
    }

    while (j <= e) {
        finalArray.push(A[j]);
        j++
    }

    while (i < p) {
        finalArray.push(A[i]);
        i++  
    }

    for(let q = s; q <= e; q++) {
        A[q] = finalArray[q-s]
    }
}
```